# Convert all values in a text file to log scale in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to convert all values in a text file to the correspondent log2 values. I have a huge text file and would be interesting to avoid R.
Nevertheless, the below R code exemplify what I want to implement in a more efficient way in bash.

```
df <- 'sam1 sam2 sam3
       2000 3000 4000
       2000 1500 1200
       2000 7000 6000'
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)

dflog <- log(df)
```

My expected output:

```
dfout <- 'sam1 sam2 sam3
       7.600902 8.006368 8.294050
       7.600902 7.313220 7.090077
       7.600902 8.853665 8.699515'

dfout <- read.table(text=dfout, header=T)
```

I will be grateful for any help to perform it in bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=log($i)}1' sams

sam1 sam2 sam3
7.6009 8.00637 8.29405
7.6009 7.31322 7.09008
7.6009 8.85367 8.69951
```

this is the quick solution, for additional decimal points you can format the output with `printf`, but I'm not sure it's needed.